# In SQL, can I reference multiple columns in a single WHERE clause?

Tags: sql

Suppose I've got a table called SAMPLE_TABLE, and its columns include USERCODE1, USERCODE2, ... USERCODE6, and that I need to run a query that excludes any rows where any of these USERCODEs = 25. I know I can write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
WHERE USERCODE1 <> 25 AND USERCODE2 <> 25 AND USERCODE3 <> 25
AND USERCODE4 <> 25 AND USERCODE5 <> 25 AND USERCODE6 <> 25
```

Is there a way to group all those USERCODE columns together in the WHERE clause without all the ANDs? Something along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
WHERE (USERCODE1, USERCODE2, USERCODE3, USERCODE4, USERCODE5, USERCODE6) <> 25
```

I'm simplifying this -- there are actually 40 USERCODE columns in the real data set, which is why I'm looking for something more concise. Any thoughts? Thanks!

EDIT: Right after I posted this, I came up with something that works, although it's a bit clunky:

```
SELECT *
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
WHERE CONCAT_WS('-', SERVICE1, SERVICE2, SERVICE3, SERVICE4, SERVICE5, SERVICE6) NOT LIKE '%25%'
```

Comment: I want to say that I've done something like `WHERE 25 NOT IN (USERCODE1, USERCODE2, USERCODE3, USERCODE4, USERCODE5, USERCODE6)` in Teradata, specifically, but I may be mistaken. Just the same, please update your question tags with the RDBMS (sql server, oracle, postgres, mysql, etc) you are using as this may be product dependent.

Comment: Also, I think it's worth mentioning, that if you have 40 `USERCODE` columns, your table schema is pretty bad. If you have control over that schema, I would highly suggest changing it so you have only two columns for this UserCode stuff: `UserCodeNumber | UserCodeValue`, then your query isn't so reliant on listing dozens of columns to function.

Comment: It sounds like this table needs to be properly normalised; you are treating what should be *data* as *structure* and the cost for this is pretty high, you will have to reference each column.

Comment: dynamic sql can do it

Comment: @JNevill: Tell me about it... and there's at least 50 aspects of this schema that are even worse! But we're stuck with it. Thanks

Comment: d-sql can assist with constructing the required query, but that query must still reference all required columns, and that almost certainly guarantees poor performance and a table scan.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, OP. That's usually the case with these kinds of questions, but we always bring it up anyway, just in case.

Comment: Your text matching strategy will fail if numbers like 125, 251 are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the specific database so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL. You can use `25 NOT IN (col1, col2, ...)` as in:

```
create table t (a int, b int, c int, d int, e int, f int);

insert ...

select * from t where 25 not in (a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Result:

```
 a   b   c   d   e   f  
 --- --- --- --- --- -- 
 1   2   3   4   5   6  
 11  12  13  14  15  16
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e7R_Q488).

Comment: I like this one, thanks! One more wrinkle: if we _also_ need to exclude any rows where one of the codes = 26, can that be incorporated into the same line, or would I just have to add it as a separate `AND` clause?

Comment: You would need a separate predicate combined with `AND` or `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no straightforward way to group all the columns together in a single comparison in the way you're describing but you can simplify your query using an INNER JOIN with a subquery to exclude any rows where any of the 40 USERCODE columns have a value of 25